# How to check if an element in list is empty?

Tags: python

I use 2 ways to check whether the element of the list is empty and they give me different result.

```
list = ['1', '2', '']

#first method
for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] == '': print("empty")

#second method
for ele in list:
    if ele == '':print("empty")
```

First method works but second method doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; they both work the same. The second would be preferred, though.

Comment: [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is a built-in and therefore not a good variable name (although that does not matter here). and i do not see why the second (more pythonic) variant should not work.

Comment: both examples are specifically checking if the element is equal to an empty string. Just keep in mind that's different from None, False, [], {}, etc....

Comment: empty string `''` is falsy in python

Comment: More pythonic should be something like: `[print('empty') for e in lst if e]`, also `if e` would be triggered if element is falsy https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: @stepuncius Oh gawd no. That's not more pythonic. Not even correct, as you forgot to negate. And that documentation doesn't say falsy but false.

Comment: @snnguyen right, but that is irrelevant when the comparison is `if x == ''`. Change it to `if not x` and that is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

They should both work. Yet if you know for sure that the content will always be a string and you are just worried about the empty ones, you could use:

```
list_ = ['1', '2', '']

for e in list_:
    if not e:
        print('empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

They both work for me. What is your output? What is your expected output?

For debugging:

```
list = ['1', '2', '']

print("First method:  ")
#first method
for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
    if list[i] == '': print("empty")


print("Second method: ")
#second method
for ele in list:
    print(ele)
    if ele == '':print("empty")
```

Output:

```
First method:  
1
2

empty
Second method: 
1
2

empty
```